# Javascript: How do I perform a action with the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the proper syntax for clicking a button and having Javascript run whatever statement you have? I did a google search but there is either multiple ways or people aren't explaining the parameters or functions very well.

Here is my code. All I want to do is when I click "attack" on my "button", the monster will lose 10 hp.

```
 document.getElementById("attack").click(); = dragon.hp = dragon.hp - 10;
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at some JS libraries like jQuery? They make this type of thing a lot easier especially for beginners.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `.click()` you are calling a function. `;` is how you end statements.  You want to *assign* a function to the `onclick` property.

You want something like this:

```
document.getElementById("attack").onclick = function(){
    dragon.hp -= 10;
};
```

Better yet, you *really* want:

```
document.getElementById("attack").addEventListener('click', function(){
    dragon.hp -= 10;
});
```

P.S. `dragon.hp -= 10;` is shorthand for `dragon.hp = dragon.hp - 10;`

Answer (score 0):

If you did something like this:

```
            <a ..... onClick="deductHpPoints()">...</a>
```

Then in your javascript:

```
            Function deductHpPoints()
            {
              //deduct logic
             }
```

Would that work for you? For something basic.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
<input type="button" value="Attack" onclick="attack()">
```

And then wherever your JavaScript lives:

```
function attack() {
    dragon.hp -= 10;
};
```

Actually, I would make the attack able to target different things:

```
function attack(target) {
    target.hp -= 10;
};
```

Maybe some radio buttons to select the target:

```
<input type="radio" name="monster" value="Dragon">
<input type="radio" name="monster" value="Beholder">
<input type="radio" name="monster" value="Minotaur">
```

Some code to find out which one was selected:

```
function discoverSelected(buttonName) {
    var theArray = document.getElementsByName(buttonName);
    for (var i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
        if (theArray[i].checked) {
            return theArray[i].value;
        };
    };
};
```

Compare that name to the array of monsters:

```
function whichMonster(monName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {
        if (monsters[i].name == monName) {
            return monsters[i];
        };
    };
};
```

Then lastly, a button to attack with!

```
<input type="button" value="Attack" onclick="attack(whichMonster(discoverSelected("monster")))">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend the response to `jQuery` library, you can do this (after calling the [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) library)

```
$("#attack").on('click', function(){
    dragon.hp -= 10;
});
```

or, in case the `#attack` button is created dynamically

```
$(document).on('click', "#attack", function(){
        dragon.hp -= 10;
    });
```