# Open Twilio webchat on clicking multiple buttons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twilio

I've integrated Twilio Webchat into my PrestaShop store and initialized the chat using JavaScript. There's a 'Chat Now' button on my header, and I want Twilio to open the chat window when this button is clicked. How can I trigger this action? I attempted to do so with the following code:

```html
<div id="twilio-webchat-widget-root"></div>

<script>
  function openChat() {
    document.getElementById("twilio-webchat-widget-root").click();
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const appConfig = {
      deploymentKey: "***************",
      theme: {
        isLight: false
      }
    }
    Twilio.initWebchat(appConfig);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How do I perform a action with the click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906389/javascript-how-do-i-perform-a-action-with-the-click-of-a-button)

Comment: @imjared, no. I wanted to know the exact callback function of Twilio that enables this invoke.